# Wait until an element becomes visible using selenium-webdriver and PjantomJS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, mocha.js

I am writing my automated test scripts using selenium-webdriver, phantomJS and mocha.

My script file is javascript file by nature.

I want to wait till an element(`<a>`) becomes completely visible. After it becomes visible, the element will be clicked.

Let me explain in details:

There are some menus and submenus. The menu is collapsible in nature. When I click on a menu, then its corresponding submenus are displayed.

My following script first iterates(And clicks) through the menu and then iterates and displays the submenu status.

```
for(var iMajor = 2; iMajor <= majorLinkLast ; iMajor++)
{   
    majorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/a";
    if(iMajor != 2)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(majorMenuXPath)).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30 * 10000);
    }   
    for(var iMinor = 1; iMinor <= minorSize[iMajor] ; iMinor++)
    {   
        minorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/ul/li["+iMinor+"]/a";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath)).isDisplayed().then(function(elem){
        console.log(elem);
    });
}
```

The above code displays the status of the submenus like:

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
true
false
true
false
true
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

I have used implicit method for making the driver wait. But still some submenus are displayed as false(means they are not visible). They should have been visible after the parent menu got clicked.

I need some help regarding the following:

1. How can I wait till the submenu is visible? After each submenu
   becomes visible, I need to perform some action.
2. Or, how can I make the submenu visible after a particular time.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="side-menu" class="nav">
    <li class="nav-header">
    <img class="logo" alt="Track Revenue" src="/images/3c4939d.png">
    <div class="logo-element"> TR </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Tr Admin Menu</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/user/">All Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/company/">All Companies</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/device/">Devices</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/email/">Send Email</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/impersonate">Impersonate User</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/admin/encrypttest">Test Encryption</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Campaigns</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <li>
    <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_overview.php">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_update_cpc.php">CPC Update</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_update_subids.php">SubID Update</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_v2.php">Add Campaign</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Stats</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/stats_campaign_v2.php">Campaign Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/stats_week_day_v2.php">Week / Day Parting Stats</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Reports</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/report_custom.php">Custom Data Reports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/report_subid.php">SubID Analysis Report</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/completed_report.php">Scheduled Reports</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#home">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    <span class="nav-label">Settings</span>
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
        <li>
        <a href="/profile/">Account</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/plan/">Plan Management</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_groups.php">Campaign Groups</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_network.php">Affiliate Networks</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_sources.php">Traffic Source</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/manage/user/">Manage Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/manage/company/">Manage Company</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/settings_rules.php">Blocking & Filter Rules</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/domains.php">Domains</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="http://demotest.com.co/main/account/campaign_archive.php">Campaign Maintenance</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Note:

I am new to selenium. I need javascript procedure to solve the problem. I have no knowledge in JAVA or Python or C#

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: without code, we can't really help you; Though from the top-of-my-hat, you should first `expect(by.css('#element').isVisible()).toBe(true)` (not sure on the `isVisible` but there's bount to be such a function) and THEN you make the `by.css('#element').click()` and afterwards `expect(something).toHaveHappenedSomewhere()` --- If you *really* need the element to be visible, I gather you can change it's class to a `display: block` one and then execute the expect

Comment: I added a small piece of code. Do you need me to add the whole script?

Comment: Nah, that's mighty cool; I made an edit to my comment, though I'll reprase it: you can make a `by.css('#element').setAttribute('class','class-with-block');` and then make the `expect`

Comment: please add the HTML DOM code

Comment: @ArtjomB. Can you please elaborate? I have to make a driver element visible.

Comment: @MoshMage, I made this piece of code `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]")).setAttribute('class','active').then(function(){});`, but its throwing error **undefined is not a function**

Comment: I think you need to `setAttribute` in the `xpath`. somthing like `By.xpath('#element').setAttribute())` not after the findElements. but then again, the `setAttribute` function can have a API specific name instead.

Comment: Don't change CSS, etc. to make the element visible... do what a user would do that would make that element appear as Artjom B. suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet helped the elements to get displayed.

```
minorMenuXPath = "//ul[contains(@id, 'side-menu')]/li["+iMajor+"]/ul/li["+iMinor+"]/a";
//Following snippet is stated for making the driver wait till the element is visble.
driver.wait(function() 
{
   return driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath));
}, 20*1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(minorMenuXPath)).then(function(elem)
{
    elem.isDisplayed().then(function(stat){
        console.log(stat);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is invisible for a reason, isn't it? Automate whatever a normal user would do to make that element visible. Sometimes sections of a page are hidden, because it there are multiple "views" on a single page. A user can usually navigate between those views by clicking on something or filling out forms. You have to automate the same interaction a user would do.